# JavaScript: How to loop a console.log and userinput after a fuction?

Tags: javascript, function, loops, user-input

```
//Console
    console.log("menu" + '\n" + "1. bacon" + "\n" + "toast");
//Variable
    var userInput = readline.sync('Menu Option');
//Function
    function menu (userInput){
        if (userInput ==`1`){
        console.log("Bacon")
        }
        if (userInput == '2'){
        console.log('Toast')
        }
        }
//Callng function
    menu();
```

Trying to loop the console.log and varuserinput after the function completes asking the user again for an input

Comment: console.log('Toast) should be console.log('Toast');

Comment: Your question is not clear.Please make change - what is your problem,what is the input and what is desired output

Answer (score 0):

```
    var readlineSync = require('readline-sync');
do{
     console.log("Menu" + "\n" + "1. Bacon" + "\n" + "2. Toast" + "\n" + "3. Quit");
     var userInput = readlineSync.question("Menu Option:");
     menu (userInput);
    }while(userInput =! "3");
    //Menu
    function menu(userInput){
     if (userInput == "1"){
      console.log("Bacon")}
     else if (userInput == "2"){
      console.log("Toast")}
    else if (userInput == "3"){
     console.log("Goodbye")}
    else{
     console.log("invalid input")}}
```

Now it loops the menu but when you enter 3 it says goodbye and invalid input